# How to fill data into container at once without temp variable in C++03

Tags: c++, c++03

Suppose I have a `Container`.

```
template<typename Type>
class Container
{
public:
    Container(int size_)
    {
        size=size_;
        data = new Type[size];
    }
    ~Container()
    {
        delete [] data;
    }

private:
    int size;
    Type* data;
};
```

I want something fill data into container at once like this

```
Container<int> container(3);
container << 100,200,300;
```

or

```
Container<int> container(3);
container.fill({100,200,300});
```

or

```
Container<int> container{100,200,300};
```

after do this, `data[0]=100`,`data[1]=200`,`data[2]=300`

I do NOT want introduce some temp variable

```
// I do not like this...
int data[]={1,2,3};
Container<int> container(3);
container.fill(data,data+3);
```

## How can I implement that in C++03?

Thanks for your time.

#### Appendix A:

Something similar is `Eigen`'s comma-initializer

```
RowVectorXd vec1(3);
vec1 << 1, 2, 3;
```

#### Appendix B:

I know it is easy using C++11 std::initializer_list to implement something like

```
Container<int> container{100,200,300};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a simple proxy object and overload `operator<<` and `operator,`. Simple example:

```
template<typename Type>
class Container {
private:
    struct Proxy {
        Type* data;
        Proxy(Type* data) : data(data) {}

        Proxy operator,(Type value) {
            *data = value;
            return Proxy(data + 1);
        }
    };

public:
    // ...

    Proxy operator<<(Type value) {        
        *data = value;
        return Proxy(data + 1);
    }
};
```

Then `container << 100, 200, 300;` will be translated into

```
container.data[0] = 100;
container.data[1] = 200;
container.data[2] = 300;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/AX5rSw)

Comment: Sir, it is so fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

If your container is following the practices and interfaces of STL containers, then it would have a `push` or `push_back` member that can add without creating a temporary listing:

```cpp
Container<int> container(size);
container.push_back(1); container.push_back(2); container.push_back(3); // etc
```

Not comfortable, certainly, but it's the "entry point" you'll probably want to build your custom solution up from. You can even implement the proxy provided by @Evg generically which means it'll work with a number of container types.

For an example of how a generic implementation works, take a look at [cxxomfort's `_seq()`](http://ryan.gulix.cl/fossil.cgi/cxxomfort/uv/html/seq___8hpp.html).

Any particular reason you don't want to introduce a temp array? If you are using any decent compiler past 1990 and you declare that array as `const`, the compiler should do away with it and result in object code that is likely better than any customized proxy, in particular if the compiler has to work with references.