# Is it is possible to construct container and filled data into it in one line using C++03?

Tags: c++, c++03

Suppose I have a `Container`.

```
template<typename Type>
class Container
{
public:
    Container(int size_)
    {
        size=size_;
        data = new Type[size];
    }
    ~Container()
    {
        delete [] data;
    }

private:
    int size;
    Type* data;
};
```

I want construct the container and fill data into it in one line like this using C++03

```
// very easy to implement using C++11 std::initializer_list
Container<int> container{100,200,300}
```

or

```
Container<int> container(100,200,300)
```

or

```
// other one line solution
```

after do this, `data[0]=100,data[1]=200,data[2]=300`.

Thanks for your time.

#### Appendix

Similiar question is

- [How to fill data into container at once without temp variable in C++03](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61315722/how-to-fill-data-into-container-at-once-without-temp-variable-in-c03)

Evg already give the answer can implement a two lines solution.

```
Container<int> container(3);
container << 100, 200, 300;
```

I still wonder is there exist the one line solution?

Comment: the solution on that other answer can already be used to do it in one line. `Container<int> container() << 1,2,3;`. This question is soo similar to the other one, that I would have rather asked for clarification on the answer instead posting the almost exact same question again

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61315722/how-to-fill-data-into-container-at-once-without-temp-variable-in-c03 ;)

Comment: @idclev463035818 Sir, that answer already allocate the space, then fill data into it. But here I want automatically detect the container's size, then fill data into it. I am sorry for my stupid because I can not understand how can we do `Container<int> container() << 1,2,3;` when the size of container does not know.

Comment: you will have to reallocated and adjust the `size` accordingly. You will end up reimplementing `std::vector`, why dont you use `std::vector` in the first place?

Comment: @idclev463035818 Sir, that link first allocate space then fill data. Here I want automatically detect the container's size. I can not find clue base on that answer.

Comment: there is no one line construrtor in C++03 for std::vector can do `std::vector<int> x{1,2,3};` but C++11 did.

Comment: yes sorry I missed the things about the size. But once you have a `insert` method that correctly handles that, it will also be easy to do the construction in a single line. Your `Container` currently has many problems. You need to read about the rule of 3/5, once you got that straight, you can apply the other answer without too much modifications

Comment: Sir, the container does have the problems. I do not show the copy constructor, copy assigen operator, copy safety on purpose to make the problem much easier understand. I just want to show that there is just a container like `array`, and I wants to construct it and fill data in one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you link can almost do that. You only need a minor modification and that is: You need to make your container resizable. This is actually the major issue. Once you have that, adapting the solution is minor. Write a `insert` method that reallocates the memory and adjusts the size then only minor modifications on the proposed solution are necessary.

There is one caveat, and this is you cannot call the constructur call methods on the constructed object and assign it to a variable in the same line without a copy. For that it is possible to provide a conversion from `Proxy` to `Container`. I would rethink if putting something on a single line is really worth this cost, when it can be done much easier on two lines.

I didn't include the implementation of `insert`, because that would be sort of a different question:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename Type>
class Container {
private:
    struct Proxy {
        Container* container;
        Proxy(Container* container) : container(container) {}

        Proxy& operator,(Type value) {
            container->insert(value);
            return *this;
        }
        operator Container() { return *container; }
    };

public:
    // ...
    void insert(const Type& value) {
        std::cout << value;
    }

    Proxy operator<<(Type value) {        
        insert(value);
        return Proxy(this);
    }
};

int main() {
    Container<int> container = (Container<int>() << 1,2,3);
}
```

Output:

```
123
```

PS:

> The problem is that, there is Container x={1,2,3,....,1000} everywhere in my project using C++11. Now, I must omove to C++03, and there is no std::itializer_list

Yes that is a problem. I suppose `1,2,3,...1000` is just an oversimplified example, otherwise you could use something similar to `std::iota` to fill the container (also only avaible since C++11, but not too difficult to implement). If that is the actual problem and you are looking for a temporary hack I would rather use plain arrays and construct the container from that:

```
int temp[] = {1,2,3,4,5 ....};
Container<int> x( &temp[0], &temp[999]);
```

Comment: Sir, your suggestion did work.But I still wonder it there any solution can do follow way. When we call `Container<int> container(1,2,3)`, actullay it is call `Container<int> container(helper)` and `helper` is implicit construct by `1,2,3`. the `helper` can implement by `std::list` which help dynamic store data and size detect. Is that possible?

Comment: @XuHui this will just shift the problem to constructing the helper. Anyhow, such mind-games make a nice exercise to see if it can be done somehow, but for any serious code I would stay away from it and write clear readable c++. Already concerning your first question, I consider an explicit `container.data[0] = 100;` much better than hiding it inside a proxy. On the long run you dont gain anything from writing such code other than making it harder to read

Comment: @XuHui consider that complexity of code is not only what you see on the surface. The net effect is that you trade one line for the caller against >10 lines in the class. Even using it many times does not make it better, because if someone not familiar with your class wants to understand what `container << 1,2,3;` does they do need to inspect that >10 lines instead of reading only 2 when you don't do anything like that

Comment: Sir, I respect your idea to write simple code. The problem is that, there is `Container<int> x={1,2,3,....,1000}` everywhere in my project using C++11. Now, I must omove to C++03, and there is no `std::itializer_list`. Set value 1000 time is too boring. So I ask the first problem, and obtain the result `Container<int> x(3);x<<1,2,3;`. But it exist the problem that the data insert by `<<` many be not same as container size. Thus here I want to detect the size automatically.

Comment: Sir, thanks for your kindness and patient. Your ps is using the range construct, just like std::vector did. It is much easier to understand. But the backness is that we must to make sure `&temp[999]` is not overflowed. It let user to consume their brain. My most curious is how to automatically  detect the size after see `1,2,3,4`

Comment: @XuHui that can be fixed by using iterators and `std::begin` and `std::end` instead of raw arrays (also only available since c++11, but also straightforward to implement in C++03). Using c-arrays does not require the user to write the size themself, I was just too sloppy when writing the PS

Comment: Sir, suppose we are using std::beign or std::end, so we need to using container like std::vector. we first store data in std::vector then copy it to my container. So the problem comes back. How can we store the data in std::vector? There is no `std::vector<int> x{1,2,3};` in C++11, so we had to using raw pointer to fill data in std::vector. It still exist  the risk of overflow.

Comment: @XuHui I am afraid you don't understand. You dont need C++11 to get a begin and end iterator to a c-array, see here: https://godbolt.org/z/YAQ__E

Comment: Ahhhh! I see! I undetstand it now~ thanks for your kindness and patient sir!

Comment: @XuHui btw thats basically what [`std::end` and `std::begin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) do for c-arrays. I just put it ina single function. I was not refering to the member functions of `std::vector`

Comment: Sir, I now fully understand :) Thanks a lot for solving all my questions!

Comment: @XuHui please read about the [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), you get much better help and it is easier to answer if you ask for your actual problem, not only your solution to that problem

Comment: I will ask question much direclty next time sir, thanks for your kindness.